# MATLAB IMAGE from int16 n-by-n-by-3

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

I have a 256*256*3 array which has int16 vith values like   -14588 , -8956, 7685, -29691, -31228

I would like to image this array by matlab image() but i could not succeeded. How can I image this file. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: It says: TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0 when imagesc used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image` cannot display int16 images, but it can display uint16 images. From the [doc of image](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/image.html):

> Image is stored as a three-dimensional (m-by-n-by-3) array of integers in the range [0, 255] (uint8) or [0, 65535] (uint16).

So you convert your int16 array A to an uint16 array. For that, try this:

```
B = uint16(int32(A)+32768);
image(B);
```

Convert to int32 to keep the sign and add 2^16 to negative values. If you have a recent Image Processing toolbox, you can use [`im2uint16`].(http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/im2uint16.html)

Another possibility is to convert A as a floating point array and scale it between 0 and 1:

```
B = (double(A)+32768)/65536;
image(B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`im2double`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/im2double.html) that rescales the data depending on the input datatype into double. You can then display the `double data` using [**`image`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/image.html) -

```
double_data = im2double(int16_imgdata);
image(double_data)
```

Comment: `'int16_imgdata` is your `256*256*3 array`. Replace that name with your variable name.

Comment: @user1949719 Check out the edited code for a better solution.